# maven eclipse wtp not putting custom <webxml> file in WEB-INF folder

Tags: maven, web.xml, eclipse-wtp, maven-war-plugin

When i deploy a webapp using eclipse wtp, the custom "webxml" file specified in pom.xml is not copied to WEB-INF folder as 'web.xml' . However the file is correctly copied in the war in the WEB-INF folder.

Here is the snippet from pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <webXml>${webXmlPath}</webXml>
        <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/web.xml</packagingExcludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

${webXmlPath} depends on the profile and has a default value:

```
<properties>
        <webXmlPath>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web-embed.xml</webXmlPath>
</properties>
```

thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use [m2e-wtp](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/), your /.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component should contain an entry like :

> `<wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/web.xml" source-path="/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web-embed.xml"/>`

That should do the trick.

Now for server adapters which support it (currently JBoss AS only), using `<packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/web.xml</packagingExcludes>` will actually prevent *any* web.xml from being deployed. Other server adapters (like Tomcat) will ignore that directive.

Comment: This helped me *A LOT*. Thank you @Fred!